# API data is returning an error

Tags: json, api, reactjs, superagent

I am using superagent to return the api data to the console, but I am greeted with these 2 errors[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
componentDidMount () {
    console.log("Did mount");

        const url = 'https://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_stores/?query=v-neck+sweater&lat=40.7575285&lng=-73.9884469&radius=5&priceRange=30:120&apiKey=0816b72b7c798c6c6994c915b0a1854d';
        superagent
        .get(url)
        .query(null)
        .set('Accept', 'text/json')
        .end((error, response) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        })   
      }
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways you can handle this:

**1. Use the server**

Make the `api.goodzer.com` request on the server then feed the browser the results. I think this is probably the best solution but if you don't have access to the server you can use option 2.

**2. Use the an Iframe**

to make the `api.goodzer.com` request. This way the request happens in its own space.